# Where can I get the missing wbemuuid?

Tags: c++, dllimport

I am trying to call

`private static extern uint WmiGetSerialNumberA(out string serialNumber);`

using

`[DllImport("wbemuuid.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint = "WmiGetSerialNumberA")]`

as in the documentation.

I want to change the SerialNumber using WMI temporary.
However it gives me the erorr message:

> Unable to load DLL 'wbemuuid.dll' or one of its dependencies

It looks like I don't have the wbemuuid.dll on my pc but only a wbemuuid.lib file.
My System is Windows 10 22H2.

I tried to find a solution online for this however I couldn't find any download for the dll or a working solution.

Answer (score -1):

Add it like this:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "wbemuuid.lib")
```

At the top of your .cpp file after the #include section.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wbemcli/nn-wbemcli-iwbemservices

Comment: How does including that *static* library in the build resolve a missing *dynamic* library in the OS?